# Python - parse through serial data and look for specific string

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I'm currently connecting to a device and am reading back x number of characters on the serial line. I want to look for a specific string after reading the serial content back.

I've been able to successfully connect to the device and can read back the contents of the serial.

```
import serial

import sys

# connect to com port
ser = serial.Serial('COM1', 115200, timeout=0)

#read serial data
data = ser.read(1000)

#output serial data
data

#step needed to parse through serial data and look for specific string - 
e.g. Hello
```

No error messages as yet

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for a pattern, use regular expressions as following-

```
import re
if re.search(r'<pattern>', data, re.MULTILINE):
    print "string found"
```

If you want to get the string matched by the pattern, try:

```
search_obj = re.search(r'<pattern>', data, re.MULTILINE)
if search_obj:
    print "String matched by the pattern is: %s" %(search_obj.group(0))
```

If you just want to check for a particular string, use python's `in` operator to check for the membership of a substring in a larger string

```
if specific_string in data:
    print "string present"
```